# How to convert one field in a multidimensional array to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

For example if I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
const coWorkers = [
{ name: "Jack", age: 40, resident_state: "Wyoming" },
{ name: "Mary", age: 30, resident_state: "New Jersey" },
{ name: "Kate", age: 20, resident_state: "Florida" },
{ name: "Gerome", age: 50, resident_state: "Texas" },
];
```

and I want to create a function to turn one field in this array (ex: state) to lowercase, how would I go about doing so?

I have tried this:

```js
const coWorkers = [
{ name: "Jack", age: 40, resident_state: "Wyoming" },
{ name: "Mary", age: 30, resident_state: "New Jersey" },
{ name: "Kate", age: 20, resident_state: "Florida" },
{ name: "Gerome", age: 50, resident_state: "Texas" },
];

function lowerCaseStates(coWorkers.resident_state){
  lowerCasing = function() {
    return coWorkers.resident_state.toLowerCase();
  }
  lowercaseStates = coWorkers.map(lowerCasing);
  console.log(lowercaseStates)
}

 lowerCaseStates()
```

How would I go about doing this while not replacing each cell in the array individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot have a dotted parameter in the function (and do not need it if you access it inside the function
2. just run directly on the string
3. You do not have a multidimensional array. You have an object array
4. You can use a function to process the complete array in one map statement - I use the ...rest to just copy the other items we are not interested in

Note I have to wrap the object in () if I do not have `=> {}` in the arrow function

```js
const coWorkers = [
{ name: "Jack", age: 40, resident_state: "Wyoming" },
{ name: "Mary", age: 30, resident_state: "New Jersey" },
{ name: "Kate", age: 20, resident_state: "Florida" },
{ name: "Gerome", age: 50, resident_state: "Texas" }
];


const lowerCase = ({resident_state, ...rest }) =>
  ({ resident_state: resident_state.toLowerCase(), ...rest });
  
const coWorkersLowerCase = coWorkers
  .map(lowerCase)

console.log(coWorkersLowerCase)
```

If you want to modify the original, you can use a forEach

```js
const coWorkers = [
{ name: "Jack", age: 40, resident_state: "Wyoming" },
{ name: "Mary", age: 30, resident_state: "New Jersey" },
{ name: "Kate", age: 20, resident_state: "Florida" },
{ name: "Gerome", age: 50, resident_state: "Texas" }
];

coWorkers.forEach(item => item.resident_state = item.resident_state.toLowerCase())

console.log(coWorkers)
```

Comment: Done! Thanks for letting me know how to accept. If it's okay to ask, is there any particular reason why the  "function" keyword is not used (like my original solution)? Is it because it would not be able to access the array from inside the function, or is it because it is simply more efficient to not put it inside?

Comment: We can use a function. It is longer and needs the return keyword: `const lowerCase = function({resident_state, ...rest }) {
  return { resident_state: resident_state.toLowerCase(), ...rest } };`

Comment: Ohhh ok I understand now. Thank you so much for everything!

Comment: No problem. I also learned today since it annoyed me to pass all three members to the function and only modify one, so I had to go and read up on ...rest spread again since I knew it existed but had not yet had a need for it. This is a great side-effect of helping people

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would go like this

```
coWorkers.map(x=>{
x.resident_state=x.resident_state.toLowerCase();
return x
})
```

Comment: 1. You are modifying the original. 2. You waste a map. Why? Just use forEach